# How to read .csv file in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I'm trying to read .csv file which can run as per the below options given in program which are:

1. Enter 1 to output all the information for all of the products in the inventory.
2. Enter 2 to output all the information for all of the products under a particular category (Bakery, Meat, Produce, Deli, Cleaning).
3. Enter 3 to add more products to the inventory

My .csv file is below:

```
MEAT,Chicken breast,14.50,8,2020-03-03,1
PRODUCE,Royal Gala apple,2.5,20,2020-03-20,1.0
MEAT,Chicken kebabs honey soy,9.0,6,2020-03-03,0.48
PRODUCE,Broccoli,2.00,33,2020-03-10,0.4
MEAT,Burger patties,10.00,8,2020-03-08,0.4
MEAT,Lamb loin chop,28.00,12,2020-03-05,0.5
PRODUCE,Nectarine,7.00,9,2020-03-09,1.8
MEAT,Beef premium mince,12.50,16,2020-02-27,0.6
PRODUCE,Avacado,2.35,10,2020-03-07,0.2
PRODUCE,Green grapes,7.00,5,2020-03-01,1.0
```

I'm able to run the first option and display all the information. I need help in option 2 and option 3.
This is my Main class:

```js
package InventorySystem;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * All that is remaining to do is task 4 & 5:
 *  1.  Implement the file reading/writing to the csv file. 
 *          hint:- Just save to the csv file on exiting (when the user presses "q") by incrementally
 *          printing each item in the LocalStore inventory (eg. store.inventory.get(i).toString()).
 *          Do the opposite when you first run the program, the very first thing program should do 
 *          is read the csv file and incrementally add each line in the file as a new object into the
 *          inventory ArrayList.
 *  2.  Implement exception handling for the file reading/writing
 *  3.  Implement data validation in case the user enters incorrect data
 */
public class Main
{

    private static String   name,
                            veganStr = "";
    private static double   basePrice,
                            weight;
    private static int      quantity,
                            day,
                            month,
                            year;
    private static boolean  vegan = false;
    
    private static LocalStore store = new LocalStore("My Food Store","35 Queen Street",35500);


    //method to get the mandatory information to create an Inventory item
    private static void getMandatory()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the item's name --> ");
        name = Keyboard.readInput();
        System.out.print("Enter the item's base price --> ");
        basePrice = Double.parseDouble(Keyboard.readInput());
        System.out.print("Enter the item quantity --> ");
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(Keyboard.readInput());
    }
    //method to get the optional items required for Deli & Bakery items
    private static void getOptional()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the expiry date --> ");
        String date = Keyboard.readInput();

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date parsedDate = null;

        try {
            parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.print("Enter the item's weight --> ");
        weight = Double.parseDouble(Keyboard.readInput());
    }
    //method to get the vegan details
    private static void getVegan()
    {
        System.out.print("Is the item suitable for vegans? Y/N --> ");
        veganStr = Keyboard.readInput();
        if(veganStr.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            vegan = true;
        }
    }
    private static void addDeliItem()
    {
        getMandatory();
        getOptional();
        getVegan();
        //add the new item
        store.inventory.add(new Deli(name,basePrice,quantity,day,month,year,weight,vegan));
    }
    private static void addBakeryItem()
    {
        getMandatory();
        getOptional();
        getVegan();
        store.inventory.add(new Bakery(name,basePrice,quantity,day,month,year,weight,vegan));
    }
    private static void addProduceItem()
    {
        getMandatory();
        getOptional();
        store.inventory.add(new Produce(name,basePrice,quantity,day,month,year,weight));
    }
    private static void addMeatItem()
    {
        getMandatory();
        getOptional();
        store.inventory.add(new Meat(name,basePrice,quantity,day,month,year,weight));
    }
    private static void addCleaningItem()
    {
        getMandatory();
        store.inventory.add(new Cleaning(name,basePrice,quantity));
    }
    private static void mainMenu() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner menuOptionIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner addOptionIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String menuAnswer,
                addOption;

        boolean cont = true;
        while (cont) {
            //show the menu to the user
            System.out.println("\n---MAIN MENU---\nEnter 1 to output all the information for all of the products in the inventory\n" +
                    "Enter 2 to output all the information for all of the products under a particular category\n" +
                    "Enter 3 to add more products to the inventory\n" +
                    "Enter q to quit the program");
            //read the user's input
            menuAnswer = menuOptionIn.nextLine();
            if (menuAnswer.equals("1") || menuAnswer.equals("2") || menuAnswer.equals("3")) {
                switch (menuAnswer) {
                    case "1":
                        //output info for all products
                        store.printAll();
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        //output info for particular category
                        System.out.println("\nWhat category item would you like to view?\n" +
                                "Enter 1 for Deli\n" +
                                "Enter 2 for Bakery\n" +
                                "Enter 3 for Produce\n" +
                                "Enter 4 for Meat\n" +
                                "Enter 5 for Cleaning\n" +
                                "Enter r to return to the menu");
                        addOption = addOptionIn.nextLine();
                        switch (addOption) {
                            case "1":
                                store.printType("Deli");
                                break;
                            case "2":
                                store.printType("Bakery");
                                break;
                            case "3":
                                store.printType("Produce");
                                break;
                            case "4":
                                store.printType("Meat");
                                break;
                            case "5":
                                store.printType("Cleaning");
                                break;
                            case "r":
                                //return to the main menu
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        //add products
                        //ask the user to select item group they wish to add
                        System.out.println("\nWhat category item would you like to add?\n" +
                                "Enter 1 for Deli\n" +
                                "Enter 2 for Bakery\n" +
                                "Enter 3 for Produce\n" +
                                "Enter 4 for Meat\n" +
                                "Enter 5 for Cleaning\n" +
                                "Enter r to return to the menu");
                        addOption = addOptionIn.nextLine();
                        switch (addOption) {
                            case "1":
                                addDeliItem();
                                break;
                            case "2":
                                addBakeryItem();
                                break;
                            case "3":
                                addProduceItem();
                                break;
                            case "4":
                                addMeatItem();
                                break;
                            case "5":
                                addCleaningItem();
                                break;
                            case "r":
                                //return to the main menu
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            } else if (menuAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        mainMenu();
                
        //print all test objects
        store.printAll();
        //print only Meat
        store.printType("Meat");

    }

}
```

This is my LocalStore class where changes needs to be done under addProduct and printType.

```js
package InventorySystem;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LocalStore 
{
    private String  supermarketName,
                    location;
    private int     maxProducts;
    public ArrayList<Inventory>  inventory = new ArrayList<>(maxProducts);
   
    public LocalStore(String n,String l,int max)
    {
        this.supermarketName = n;
        this.location = l;
        this.maxProducts = max;
    }
    //add product to inventory array
    public void addProduct(Inventory inv)
    {
        if(inventory.size()<maxProducts)
        {
            inventory.add(new Inventory(inv));
            System.out.println("Inventory Successfully added");
        }
        else if(inventory.size() == maxProducts)
        {
            System.out.println("Inventory full");
        }
    }
    public void printAll() throws FileNotFoundException {
        /*for(int i=0;i<inventory.size();++i)
        {
            System.out.println(inventory.get(i).toString());*/

            final String FILE_NAME = "productList.csv";
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME));
            while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(scnr.nextLine());
            }

            scnr.close();
        }

    public void printType(String type)
    {   //check for Deli
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Deli"))
        {
            System.out.println("Deli Items...");
            for(int i=0;i<inventory.size();++i)
            {
                if(inventory.get(i) instanceof Deli)
                {
                    System.out.println(inventory.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
        }
        //check for Bakery
        else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Bakery"))
        {
            System.out.println("Bakery Items...");
            for(int i=0;i<inventory.size();++i)
            {
                if(inventory.get(i) instanceof Bakery)
                {
                    System.out.println(inventory.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
        }
        //check for Produce
        else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Produce"))
        {
            System.out.println("Produce Items...");
            for(int i=0;i<inventory.size();++i)
            {
                if(inventory.get(i) instanceof Produce)
                {
                    System.out.println(inventory.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
        }
        //check for Meat
        else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Meat"))
        {
            System.out.println("Meat Items...");
            for(int i=0;i<inventory.size();++i)
            {
                if(inventory.get(i) instanceof Meat)
                {
                    System.out.println(inventory.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
        }
        //check for Cleaning
        else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Cleaning"))
        {
            System.out.println("Cleaning Items...");
            for(int i=0;i<inventory.size();++i)
            {
                if(inventory.get(i) instanceof Cleaning)
                {
                    System.out.println(inventory.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
        }
        //inform user no matches exist
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No items match your search...");
        }
    }
    //set and get supermarket details
    public void setSupermarketName(String n)
    {
        this.supermarketName = n;
    }
    public String getSupermarketName()
    {
        return this.supermarketName;
    }
    public void setSupermarketLocation(String l)
    {
        this.location = l;
    }
    public String getSupermarketLocation()
    {
        return this.location;
    }
    public void setMaxProducts(int m)
    {
        this.maxProducts = m;
    }
    public int getMaxProducts()
    {
        return this.maxProducts;
    }

}
```

Comment: You do not show how you are trying to use this code.  What problems are you facing?  Why are you trying to re-event the wheel (how about open source csvReader library).  Also what is all that messing around with `instanceOf` - definitely code smell.

Comment: I'm calling the local store class in my main class. So when I run the Main program it gives below output:

Enter 1 to output all the information for all of the products in the inventory.
Enter 2 to output all the information for all of the products under a particular category (Bakery, Meat, Produce, Deli, Cleaning).
Enter 3 to add more products to the inventory

When I enter 1 it displays all the information of the csv file which is inventory. The problem I'm facing is when I enter 2 it doesn't show the list of products under specified category. @ScaryWombat

Comment: @ScaryWombat and with option 3, I'm not able to add products in the list which is csv file. Hope I was able to explain my problem.

Comment: When you add a product you are just adding a `Inventory` object `inventory.add(new Inventory(inv));` - what is this `instanceOf` stuff?  [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ScaryWombat You mean instanceOf category? like instanceOf bakery or instanceOf Meat??

Comment: CSV is not as simple as you might think, how do you handle an occurrence of `,` within a column?  Better to use a dedicated API

Comment: @MadProgrammer will you be able to explain with code?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm trying to read a particular category and whatever products comes under that category from CSV file